# WPF selecting an Item in a ListBox from the ViewModel using SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm new to MVVM/WPF and after a few hours of research, not finding any really useful/working answer for my project I decided to give it a go and try asking here.

I would like to select an Item from my Listbox, which uses a List as an ItemSource.

Relevant ViewModel:

```
public class FavoriteStructureVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    public ObservableCollection<FavoriteDataVm> Favorites { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
    private FavoriteDataVm _selectedItem;
    public FavoriteDataVm SelectedItem
    {
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            var item = (FavoriteDataVm)_selectedItem;
            if (item.Type == FavoriteDataType.Add)
            {
                SelectedIndex = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ListBox contains a few items by default, the last one always being one of the type `Add`, which if selected, may add a new item and select it by default or select the previously selected item if no new item is added. **For Simplicity** the selected item will just be 1 regardless of wether a new item is added or not.

No matter where and what I tried to update with `OnPropertyChanged` it didn't update the SelectedIndex in the view, however, by adding/inserting a new `FavoriteDataVm` into `ObservableCollection<FavoriteDataVm> Favorites`, the `SelectedIndex` in the view gets updated.
The process of adding a new item to the list does not always occur, nonetheless I'd like to always update the `SelectedIndex`.

Relevant XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="favMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Favorites}" SelectionMode="Single" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                         BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Height="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         >
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Border Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>

                    <!--changing default orientation-->
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{x:Null}"
                                Width="60" Height="60" CornerRadius="30" Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Name}">


                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="60" Height="60" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                                    <Image.Clip>
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" Center="30,30"/>
                                    </Image.Clip>
                                </Image>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

I found a workaround to just create a dummy item and remove it, since adding something seems to update the `SelectedIndex`in the view. I don't see it as a solution as it comes with a lot of drawbacks.

So this kinda raises two questions actually:

- How do I get to update the `SelectedIndex` of the ListBox?

And a beginner-question, since I'm new to MVVM:

- Is this a correct implementation of MVVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I get to update the SelectedIndex of the ListBox?

You can get the selected index by getting the index of the `SelectedItem` in the source collection:

```
int selectedIndex = (SelectedItem != null && Favorites != null) ? Favorites.IndexOf(SelectedItem) : -1;
```

And you can select an item by setting the `SelectedItem` property:

```
SelectedItem = Favorites[1]; //selects the second item
```

You shouldn't bind both the `SelectedItem` and the `SelectedIndex` properties of the `ListBox`. These must be synchronized. Remove `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"` from your XAML.

Also note that if you intend to update a source property dynamically, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` for this property for the view to refresh:

```
private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }
    set { _selectedIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex"); }
}

private FavoriteDataVm _selectedItem;
public FavoriteDataVm SelectedItem
{
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the SelectedIndex
The declaration should be as follows

```
     private int _selectedIndex ;
     public int SelectedIndex{ 
     get{return _selectedIndex }; 
     set{_selectedIndex=value;OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex") }; 
     }
```

This way the list will be notified when the selectedindex changes

*"Sorry if there are any typos, i wrote this directly here and not in a code editor so you might get typos"*

Comment: thanks for taking the time to read my question!  I didn't try to put the event there yet so it might prove to work (most probably). I'll give it a try later when I'm back home and update this thread as needed